# dropzone.js - how to fire a file upload via api?

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js for file uploading.
I want to know how to fire a file upload via dropzone.js API ... I mean without dragging or input but calling a function passing file path?

Answer (score 0):

What's your use case? Why not just use something that will directly talk to your backend file processing?

Comment: when you release a file on to dragzone dropzone.js library creates the file.previewElement html that shows the uploaded file's thumbnail so I want to simulate this event. I've also customized both client and server events associated to dropzone.js upload success so I want to perform a programmatically upload and inherit all these behaviors.

Comment: You probably want to checkout the api, it appears there is an addFile method if you have a dropzone instance that you can queue up the files. See link below

https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/-/blob/master/src/dropzone.js#L1531